# created temp table in C#,i tried to copy tabls in it, an sqlexception(Invalid object name '#xyz'.)is it right way to create temp table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ado.net

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Amit\Documents\ghf.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(("create table  #xyz(pid int, pname nvarchar(50),pamount nvarchar(50),cid int,cname nvarchar(50)"), con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);   

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}


SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Amit\Documents\ghf.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into #xyz (pid, pname, pcost , cid ,cname) select  product.pid,product.pname,product.pcost ,category.cid ,category.cname  from product inner join category on product.cid = category.cid", con);

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temp table is only visible to the connection that created it.

To use a temp table your insert `SqlCommand` must use the same `con` object the create table `SqlCommand` used without the connection being closed in-between.

To use the code as-is you must make the table be a actual table instead of a temp table (Get rid of the #), but your `button1_click` event handler will need to check if the table exists first before you try to create it and the data from the previous run will still be in it.